# открытие CSV в эксель

Tags: excel, csv

есть файлы в формате .CSV которые надо открывать в экселе и чтоб данные сразу были разбиты на колонки, а не каждый раз делать "текст по столбцам"

как включить по умолчанию?

Answer (score 1):

Настройки - дополнительно - Использовать системные разделители

Снять галочку и поставить разделитель целой и дробной части - "точка", а разрядов "запятая"

Answer (score 0):

Если открывать *.csv* с помощью *VBA*, нужно указать локальные настройки ( *local:=True*)

```
Sub OpenCSV()
Dim wBook As Workbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        If .Show = True Then
            Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=.SelectedItems(1), local:=True)
            Set wBook = Nothing
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```